# Convert pdf to text and search content with line number in pdf using php

Tags: php, pdf

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/class.pdf2text.php');
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('abc.pdf');
$a->decodePDF();
$file1=$a->output();
echo $file1;
$searchText = "download";
if (strstr($file, $searchText)) 
{
    echo 'found'.' '.$searchText;
}
else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

with this code i am able to convert pdf to text.i want to search content within that pdf with line number.I am not able to get line number...

Comment: Are you sure that the class you are using sorts the text by appearance and lines? If the class is [this](https://code.google.com/p/lucene-silverstripe-plugin/source/browse/trunk/thirdparty/class.pdf2text.php?r=19) one I don't see any logic in view to sorting - not text nor pages.

Comment: This class only convert pdf to text.. I want some class so that i can search text with line number

Comment: We offer a [component](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-extractor/details/) (not free!) that allows you to extract single words including their bounding boxes. It should allow you to rebuild lines from that (for simple documents). If this would be a solution for you I'm happy to give some code as an answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 $content = shell_exec('abc.pdf -');
```